# Converting String into Char[] changes length of the variable

Tags: c#, string, char

I am using Char[] and converting it as secured string to encrypt and decrypt a string values.

Below is the code piece I am using for creating encryption key

```
char[] keyChars = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' }; // This is in key vault now.

var _key = new SecureString();
foreach (var chars in keyChars)
{
_key.AppendChar(chars); // key length is 8
}
```

I have saved this key in azure key vault and fetching it and output is returned in string. Now I want to convert the string value into char[].

I tried using the code but the variable length differs. Due to this, plain text returns different value when encrypting.

```
string keyVaultSecret = "'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'"; // length 38
string[] arrayString = new[] { keyVaultSecret };
var charArrayList = arrayString.Select(
     str => str.ToCharArray()).ToList(); // charArrayList length is 1 here
```

Can somebody please help on how to convert String into Char[] without changing the variable length.

Comment: The equivalent `string` would be: "12345678". Your `keyVaultSecret` includes all the characters for spaces, single quotes, and commas.

Comment: `arrayString.Split(',').Select( x => x[1] ).ToArray()`

Comment: I fixed comments for you - unfortunately it did not make question much better, but at least it matches behavior of the code... You may want to [edit] question more to clarify why you expected that code to produce different results and how you measured length of `charArrayList` to be 38 when it is clearly 1.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Sorry I didn't explained my question briefly. I would be mindful and clear next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you may try something like this:

```
string keyVaultSecret = "'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'";
var arrayString = keyVaultSecret
                        .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => x.Replace('\'', ' '))
                        .Select(x => x.Trim());
    
var charArray = string.Join(string.Empty, arrayString).ToCharArray();
```